# Should questions that seem eminently googleable be closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Example 1](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/26/43):

> Is there any health risk in cellular phones?
>
> Cellular phones are taking ever increasing part in our lives, and I keep hearing people saying they are harmful to our health.
>
> Are there any scientific researches so far proving or disproving those claims?
>
> If harmful, what factors are in place e.g. cellular phone model, signal strength, etc?

[Example 2](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/737/43):

> How do ultrasonic humidifiers compare with filter-based humidifiers?
>
> I wonder how ultrasonic humidifiers compare with filter-based humidifiers in terms of how healthy it is to use them. Amongst other things, I am worried about indoor particle concentrations.
>
> Assume that the user is a healthy individual (e.g. no hyper-sensitivity to pneumonitis)

[Example 3](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/642):

> How to detect colon cancer?
>
> How can a person get to know that he/she is suffering from colon cancer? What are the symptoms, and how long does it take for them to appear?

Should these questions be closed because they seem eminently googleable?

Comment: A downvote means yes or no?

Comment: Getting results with Google and making sense of them are not always the same.

Comment: @JoeW I agree, that's why I have no clue whether those downvotes mean yes or no.

Comment: A somewhat related question: http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/214/how-do-we-handle-questions-primarily-just-asking-for-references

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, your question is slightly misleading. The original question  upon which I commented consisted of one line only:

> I wonder how ultrasonic humidifiers compare with filter-based humidifiers in terms of how healthy it is to use them.

You're now asking about a subsequently edited question.

I would not have made the same comment(s) had this actually been your original question.

The question in essence is important, though, and it can be rephrased as

> Are one line "I wonder" questions showing no research effort on topic for this site?

That depends somewhat on the line, I think. But in general, I think this kind of question is ultimately not a very good one. And I believe many SE sites have the same problem.

My opinion on this matter has already been expressed [here](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217/) and [here](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/general-reference-questions), and is currently being discussed obliquely [here](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/choosing-custom-off-topic-close-reasons).

One line questions are easy, but they assume the answerer knows what you're talking about. For your original question, the reader has to guess somewhat: Is it about mold in the unit? Calcium in the air? Droplet size? Percent humidity achieved? Which health benefit is he referring to?

The guesswork discourages good answers, and good *answerers*. I can see someone taking the time and posting a researched answer, only to be met in comments with, "I wasn't asking about that, I was asking about *this*" (which should have been stated in the first place.)

Comment: My question is just one amongst many other easily Googleable questions. Also, I make the difference between one liner questions and easily Googleable questions.